# Node `net` module IPC server intermitent

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, ipc

Following the official node documentation of `net` and `child_process` modules, I archived this: a server that spawns a child and connect through `net` module. But the connection is intermittent. The code is self explanatory, but I've add details in the code comments:

```js
// server.js
const childProcess = require('child_process').fork('child.js');
const server = require('net').createServer((socket) => {
    console.log('got socket connection'); // this callback is intermitent
    socket.on('data', (stream) => {
        console.log(stream.toString());
    })
});

server.on('connection', () => {
    console.log('someone connected to server'); // this is running only if the code above runs (but its intermitent)
});

server.on('listening', () => {
    console.log('server is listening'); // this is the first log to execute
    childProcess.send('server', server); // send the server connection to forked child
});

server.listen(null, function () {
    console.log('server listen callback'); // this is the second log to execute
});
```

```js
// child.js
console.log('forked'); // this is the third log to execute
const net = require('net');

process.on('message', (m, server) => {
    if (m === 'server') {
        const socket = net.connect(server.address());
        socket.on('ready', () => {
            console.log('child is ready'); // this is the fourth log to execute
            socket.write('child first message'); // this is always running
        })
    }
});
```

the expected log when execute `node server` is:

```
server is listening
server listen callback
forked
child is ready
got socket connection
someone connected to server
child first message
```

but as the socket callback (at `createServer`) is intermitent, we get this 50% of times:

```
server is listening
server listen callback
forked
child is ready
```

IDK what to do anymore, already tried everything I could... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found what was the problem... when I read the documentation I misunderstood that literally the `net` server is being sent to the child process to share the "connections" to divide the processing in more than one process, and what I was trying to archive was just an 2 way communication with the forked child. I'll let this answer here if someone arrive at the same problem as me. This is the final code:

```js
// server.js
const childProcess = require('child_process').fork('child.js');
const server = require('net').createServer((socket) => {
    console.log('got socket connection');
    socket.on('data', (stream) => {
        console.log(stream.toString());
    })
});

server.on('connection', () => {
    console.log('someone connected to server');
});

server.listen(null, function () {
    childProcess.send(server.address());
});
```

```js
// child.js
console.log('forked');
const net = require('net');

process.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.port) {
        const socket = net.connect(message);
        socket.on('ready', () => {
            console.log('child is ready');
            socket.write('child first message');
        })
    }
});
```